# Servicestack - cannot read or set cookies from C# Client

Tags: servicestack

I'm having an issue with ServiceStack and cookies - i'm not able to either read, nor set cookies on my service, from the built in C# JsonServiceClient.

The webservices are running, on SSL, on this domain:

```
https://sites.sub.domain.co.uk/Api/
```

and the website calling the services is located here:

```
https://sites.sub.domain.co.uk/Website/
```

When I attempt to set a cookie in a service, thus:

```
this.Response.Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
```

where `cookie` is set with a domain of `.domain.co.uk`, nothing happens. The service executes exactly as expected and returns the expected response, but the cookie is not set, and there is no exception.

I've also attempted to do this in a response filter, using the provided `res` object, with the same results.

Secondly, when the services are called using a c# client, no cookies appear to be getting sent either. I'm logging out the entire request on every request, in my AppHost,

```
RequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => { Log(req.Cookies); });
```

and the cookies are always blank, although I can clearly see in the browser that there are several cookies present, and fiddler shows a `Cookie` header full of stuff on the request.

The call being made is a very bog standard `JsonServiceClient` `POST` request, made from a code behind on an aspx page:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("somewhere");

var response = client.Post(new RequestForStuff());
```

Any suggestions most welcome.

**Update**

While investigating, i've called one of the services via an html form post, and this does have the cookie collection by the time I log the request...all the cookies i'd expect to see are there...

**Another Update**

I've continued testing the services using different means. When using the REST console in Chrome, the cookies are sent by the browser, and the cookies i'm attempting to create on the response, are both working correctly, but again, when calling the same service with the same arguments, from a c# JsonServiceClient, cookies are neither sent, nor set.

The headers from the successful request (from REST console) (Serialized to json in log file):

```
{
  "Header": "Connection",
  "Value": "keep-alive"
},
{
  "Header": "Content-Length",
  "Value": "124"
},
{
  "Header": "Content-Type",
  "Value": "application/json"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept",
  "Value": "application/json"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept-Charset",
  "Value": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept-Encoding",
  "Value": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept-Language",
  "Value": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
},
{
  "Header": "Cookie",
  "Value": massive load of stuff...
},
{
  "Header": "Host",
  "Value": "sites.sub.domain.co.uk"
},
{
  "Header": "User-Agent",
  "Value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31"
},
{
  "Header": "Origin",
  "Value": "chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn"
}
```

And from the unsuccessful c# client call:

```
{
  "Header": "Content-Length",
  "Value": "124"
},
{
  "Header": "Content-Type",
  "Value": "application/json"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept",
  "Value": "application/json"
},
{
  "Header": "Accept-Encoding",
  "Value": "gzip,deflate,gzip, deflate"
},
{
  "Header": "Expect",
  "Value": "100-continue"
},
{
  "Header": "Host",
  "Value": "sites.sub.domain.co.uk"
}
```

I've played about with the headers on the request:

```
JsonServiceClient.HttpWebRequestFilter = f => f.Headers.Add(...
```

but to no avail.

**Update with fix**

Following the answer from paacshpa, I put this code in the client:

```
JsonServiceClient.HttpWebResponseFilter = d =>
{
   foreach (Cookie co in d.Cookies)
    {
        var htc = new HttpCookie(co.Name, co.Value) { Domain = co.Domain, Path = "/" };
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(htc);
    }
};
```

and presto, cookies in the browser.

Comment: Does cookie.Secure = true ?

Comment: Nah - weak question in retrospect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **and the cookies are always blank, although I can clearly see in the browser that there are several cookies present, and fiddler shows a Cookie header full of stuff on the request.**
- **The call being made is a very bog standard JsonServiceClient POST request, made from a code behind on an aspx page:**

The 2 comments above, make me think there may be some confusion in how the C# client's request/response data is being shared (short answer: it's not) when a request is issued from some other source (ie a Browser or Fiddler).

If you make a request from a Browser to page1.aspx and the code behind has

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("somewhere");

var response = client.Post(new RequestForStuff());
```

any Cookies added in the RequestForStuff Service are added only to the to `client` variable/ServiceClient and **not** to the Cookies in the response to the Browser. You essentially have a request/response (from C# client) within a request/response (from the Browser). The Cookies are not shared between the 2 'interactions'.

You could pull the Cookies out of the `client` variable and add them to the response from the original request.

```
foreach(Cookie c in client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(newUri("https://sites.sub.domain.co.uk")))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(c.Name, c.Value));           
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comments, and yeah, it makes sense. From what you're saying, i'm wasting my time trying to set cookies on the service when it's being called from a c# client that's within another request/response context, yes?

Comment: Pretty much yes...but, you're not wasting your time because time with ServiceStack is never wasted time :) - But, the cookies you're looking for will never be in the 'outer' context unless you take them out of the C# client and put them there.

Comment: Yeah - tested this now and got a solution. Thanks for the help paaschpa.